# Associating the second word of a sentence to a variable. (Python)

Tags: python, variables, sentence

I'm currently trying to perform this, but my book for class doesn't show anything in relation to Boolean variables or anything related to this problem. I've been looking online for a while and everything is way too complicated for something that should be simple according the unit. If the solution is posted here, what was typed in to find it? Maybe I need to rephrase my question.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMSEx.png

Comment: Yes, this question needs a lot of work. Start with [ask]. We have no idea what book you are talking about, or what your assignment is, what you've been learning or any of that. Also, I don't know why you refer to boolean variables, there is nothing in your image or your text that implies that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def getSecondWord(sentence):
    res = sentence.split(' ')[1]
    if res.endswith('.'):
        return res[:-1]
    else:
        return res

inputSentence = 'broccoli is delicious'
secondWord = getSecondWord(inputSentence)

print("second word is:", secondWord)
```

Comment: I appreciate it! The answer ended up coming to:

secondWord = sentence.split(' ')[1]